# Flutter: body not updating when index is from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a BottomBar class to create a TabBar.
It has a property named `currentIndex`, that is updated when I click any tab. And this seems to work.

Before creating the Scaffold, I make an instance of the class in this way:
`BottomBar b = const BottomBar();`

I use it as `bottomNavigationBar` in this way: `bottomNavigationBar: b`

and then the body is selected from an array name using the index: `tabs[b.currentIndex]`,

Why is not updating the body when the `currentIndex` changes? It seems something (refresh?) is missing.

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final tabs = [const PageDashboard(), const PageProfile()];
    
      BottomBar b = const BottomBar();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: tdGreen,
            title: const Text("test"),
          ),
          body: tabs[b.currentIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: b,
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: simply because your `HomePage` doesn't know that `currentIndex` has changed

Comment: you may want to use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what BottomBar() is, so let's assume it's a randomly created widget below.

you need to use setState() method.

I've written a brief example code to make it easier to understand.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("test"),
        ),
        body: tabs[currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(func: func),
      ),
    );
  }

  func(int index) {
    setState(() => currentIndex = index);
  }
```

You can change the currentIndex using setState like `func()` above.

```
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(int index) func;
  BottomBar({Key? key, required this.func});

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: [
      InkWell(
        child: Text('111'),
        onTap: () => widget.func(0),
      ),
      InkWell(child: Text('222'), onTap: () => widget.func(1)),
    ]));
  }
}

class PageDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Hello, World!1111',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
    );
  }
}

class PageProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Hello, World!2222',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
    );
  }
}
```